# How to retrieve the story or news id detail by scraping the web using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape the web with puppeteer to get news title and image url. I just want to access news detail of each image url and title.

Here is the code I already made. How can i do that?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function run () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto("https://news.ycombinator.com/");
            let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
                let results = [];
                let items = document.querySelectorAll('a.storylink');
                items.forEach((item) => {
                    results.push({
                        url:  item.getAttribute('href'),
                        text: item.innerText,
                    });
                });

                return results;
            })

            browser.close();
            return resolve(urls);
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}

run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: https://www.skysports.com/football/news         this is list response  . i want also detail of each  like url  detail body paragraph  https://www.skysports.com/football/news/11709/12007779/norwich-player-tested-positive-for-coronavirus-since-returned-negative-sample-says-stuart-webber

Comment: Hey Joe, can you please specify a bit what is the exact question/help that you need? Your script seems to do the job: collects all the urls an the titles to an object.

Comment: i want detail of each news like news link :skysports.com/football/news  @theDavidBarton i want this detail   https://www.skysports.com/football/news/11709/12007779/norwich-player-tested-positive-for-coronavirus-since-returned-negative-sample-says-stuart-webber

Comment: yes it collect title and  ulr . i want detail of each  here is sigle detail https://www.skysports.com/football/news/11709/12007779/norwich-player-tested-positive-for-coronavirus-since-returned-negative-sample-says-stuart-webber

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to have: `{url: 'https://first-news-url.com/news-01', text: 'News 01 title', detail: 'textContent of the article on https://first-news-url.com/news-01'}`. And you want to do it on such list like (current first articles in the feed): http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#release_4.3, https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.1145/3226595, https://blog.tonari.no/why-we-love-rust etc. So for multiple pages with different markup structure, am I correct?

Comment: Yes @theDavidBarton  i want articles too